# call sql procedure from java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, playframework, ebean

i want to call saved sql procedure from java using ebean.
i am using this code:

```
String sql = "call copy_lov_Countries(?)";
CallableSql cs = Ebean.createCallableSql(sql);
cs.registerOut(1, Types.INTEGER);
Ebean.execute(cs);
```

It reaches the procedure but it does not run right. it never copies any data!!

any idea??

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String sql = "CALL copy_lov_Countries(:param)";
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
statement.registerOutParameter("param", Types.INTEGER);
statement.execute();
connection.commit();
```

The code works with Oracle, should work also with MySQL. The principle is same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Integer returnValue = (Integer) cs.getObject(1);` after `Ebean.execute(cs);`
And post it here What it gives ?

**Update**
:Make the follwing changes to your code

```
Ebean.beginTransaction();  
try {  
String sql = "call copy_lov_Countries(?)";
CallableSql cs = Ebean.createCallableSql(sql);
cs.registerOut(1, Types.INTEGER);
Ebean.execute(cs);

 } finally {  
   Ebean.endTransaction();  
}
```

Comment: i did. but same thing no data is copied.

Comment: it returns the number 13 . which is the number of rows that should be inserted in the table. however the table is empty!!